# Disable fake GPS location using ionic2 typescript

Tags: ionic2, typescript2.0

I am creating an application using `Ionic2 with angular2 and Typescript2`. the main idea of the application is to detect the user location.

and due to the need to make sure that this data is correct we need to make sure that users don't fake their locations.

after a lot of search I found the following answer [Detect or avoid mock GPS location](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/detect-or-avoid-mock-gps-location/32406) but this answer can't help me a lot because this plugin uses `javascript` not `typescript` and i am facing a problem in using it

So, Is it possible to check or preventing a user from faking their GPS location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Typescript IS JavaScript.**

You have three options to operate the plugin and let typescript compile

1. Declare it as a known javascript var
       declare var plugins;

   ```
   plugins.fakeLocation.check(function(IsEnabledMockLocations){
        console.log(IsEnabledMockLocations);
   });
   ```
2. Writing a custom typing for it

   ```
   declare namespace plugins {
       export namespace fakeLocation {
            export function check(callback: Function): void;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Use any casting

   ```
   (<any>window).plugins.fakeLocation.check(function(IsEnabledMockLocations){
         console.log(IsEnabledMockLocations);
   });
   ```

Comment: I've tried all the three solutions but none of them work for me. the error in the first solution is plugins is not defined. the error in the second solution is that type script don't see the javascript function even after adding the javascript reference to index.html. the third one gave me an error in plugins too "plugins is not defined "

Comment: Are you testing this on your phone and did ionic plugin add https://github.com/tomloprod/cordova-plugin-fakelocation.git?

Comment: no, i am testing it in the browser. and yes i did add plugin from github repository

Comment: All plugins are only available on the mobile device

Comment: Ok, will test in Mobile. i will use the third solution should i need to include the plugin javascript file as a reference in the index.html anything else should i do?

Comment: Nothing, cordova takes care of that

Comment: If I use the therd options, I get this error: core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'fakeLocation' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fakeLocation' of undefined